# Check if a relation is completly inside an area

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

I wanted to get all federal states in Germany via Overpass. With this query I get almost the desired result:

```
[out:json];

relation(51477);
map_to_area -> .germany;
relation(area.germany)["type"="boundary"]["boundary"="administrative"]["admin_level"="4"];

out tags;
```

https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/1alL

Unfortunately one of the results is not a German federal state: Groningen

Groningen is actually an area in the Netherlands, but because of the border parts are within German territory.

To fix this result, I thought check if each relation is **completly** in the territory of Germany. But I'm quite new to Overpass and the syntax is a bit complicated to understand.

Any idea if this is possible? Or is it even a bug that OVerpass returns Groningen even though only a part of it is inside of Germany (according to OpenStreetMap data)?

Answer (score 0):

### Filter using other specific tags

It is always easier to look into such towns ([Groningen](https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/47826), [Berlin](https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/62422)) in OSM and compare tags. OSM change with time, people collect more info which make it easy to filter and search.

Here another way to go:

```
[out:csv(::id,name,admin_level)];

relation
  ["ISO3166-2"~"^DE-"]
  ["boundary"="administrative"]
  ["admin_level"="4"];

out tags;
```

> ```
> @id   name    admin_level
> 28322 Mecklenburg-Vorpommern  4
> 51529 Schleswig-Holstein  4
> 62341 Rheinland-Pfalz 4
> 62366 Thüringen   4
> 62372 Saarland    4
> 62422 Berlin  4
> 62467 Sachsen 4
> 62504 Brandenburg 4
> 62607 Sachsen-Anhalt  4
> 62611 Baden-Württemberg   4
> 62650 Hessen  4
> 62718 Bremen  4
> 62761 Nordrhein-Westfalen 4
> 62771 Niedersachsen   4
> 62782 Hamburg 4
> 2145268   Bayern  4
> ```